# How to allow user to edit text-style in UITextView? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a simple note-taking iOS application and I want to allow the user to style text.

Specifically, I want the the user to be able to highlight their text and style it (bold, italic or underline) using options presented in the system cut/copy/paste window not dissimilar from what pops up in Mail or Notes.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
var text:String = ""
var masterView:ViewController!
//THe following are here so I can attempt to allow rich text editing in the UITextView.
var isRichtext: Bool = true
var allowsEditingTextAttributes: Bool = true
```

I tried this in order to allow the user to edit text attributes but when the text is selected in my app I don't see any options? What am I missing?

[No options to style text for the user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0KEh.png)

I have been having some trouble finding the documentation or a tutorial showing me how enable this in UITextView. Can anyone point me in the direction of some documentation that could show me how to do this?

Comment: Have you look at the reference documentation for `UITextView`? There is a property for this.

Comment: I came across this question a while ago. It only seems to answer my question in part. I've added a comment to the question.

Comment: That other answer fully answers your question. Enable that property and you have what you want.

Comment: I posted a comment restating my question there and it was deleted by moderators stating I should ask another question.

Comment: Why are you declaring a variable named `allowsEditingTextAttributes` instead of simply setting that property on your text view?